# KVM latest version

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, hypervisor

So this might be a stupid question. But I'm comparing four different hypervisors (Hyper-V, KVM, RHV, vSphere) and one of the criteria is 'future development'.

I was looking for the newest version of KVM but I can't really find it. KVM 1.2.0 seems to be the last stable release, but that was in 2012. Is KVM still being developed and does it have updates occasionally? What is the latest version of KVM right now?

Answer (score 2):

> The KVM project used to maintain a fork of QEMU called qemu-kvm. All feature differences have been merged into QEMU upstream and the development of the fork suspended.
>   http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/KVM

Meaning KVM continues entirely in the Linux kernel and QEMU projects. Have a look in your distro's package manager for the kvm user space tools.

KVM is the hypervisor for RHEV and other platforms, it is Red Hat's virtualization host strategy.

Actually, if you are comparing products with management tools, it maybe doesn't make sense to compare RHEV to KVM. Consider virt-manager and other libvirt clients, which also can be powered by KVM.

Comment: It's called RHV now, since version 4

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know where I can find the limitations on scalibility of KVM? Like max. logical cpu's per host, max. RAM per host, max. virtual cpu's etc. I've been looking everywhere but can't really find it, only for old versions.

Comment: Red Hat publishes supported virtualization limits, for example. If you think you will be pushing technical or licensing limitations you'll want to contact the vendor anyway.